# How meaningful is the notion of now here on Earth?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, consciousness, physics

Special relativity and the lack of a now moment is causing me a bit of grief.

How meaningful is the notion of now here on Earth between each of us? Does the lack of an objective now moment in any way change how we should think about our friends and family and philosophy between the relationships we form?

My friends' and families' notion of now doesn't ever line up with mine; what does this mean for their conscious perceptions? Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Regarding things like time dilation, hypersurfaces of simultaneity etc

Comment: you have to write about your perception of now. If your perception doesn't line up to other's notice, that can be, why not. People can be different in memories, perceptions, waitings. This world is different and it is normal that your observer is able to notice this. 

This is a point of psychological, when your notice is not coincide to many others( more then 2-3+) you have inner conflict to agree with others or to become a "conflict" with group. Our brains usually have primacy society instinct "to agree with group" and if you don't do, you can get distress. So i think this is it.

Comment: Special relativity does not say there is no "now" moment, just that it's much more difficult to establish than we think intuitively. Even if your twin brother takes a very fast rocket and experiments time dilation, provided you know his precise schedule and he abides by it, and you can do the proper calculations based on his rocket acceleration and trajectory, it is perfectly possible to know what he is doing in his rocket at any arbitrary time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Special relativity has no bearing whatsoever on your day to day activities. If you are moving relative to someone else, then yes in theory you will be time dilated in their frame of reference and they will be time dilated in yours, but the effects at everyday speeds are so utterly minuscule compared with the typical reaction time of your brain that you can ignore them completely.

As for the relativity of simultaneity, that too is dependent on speed but it is also dependent on distance, decreasing with proximity, so the effects are again absolutely negligible in day to day life.

In any event, you should not equate the effects of the relativity of simultaneity with the lack of a common local 'now'. If you are not sure what I mean by that, please post a question of physics SE.

Comment: So do you think this means we should think about the identity of our loved ones in any other way than normally?

Comment: I can confidently assure you that the implications of special relativity should have no bearing whatsoever on your relationships with your loved ones.

Comment: If you say this, i trust you.

Comment: @άνθρωπος thank you. I am a very trustworthy person, except when I am playing intellectual pranks, but feel free to come back to me at any time if you have the slightest doubt about my assurances.

Comment: I've been worried about this for a few days actually, that special relativity and the contrasting planes if simultaneity mean that my reality will never contain the you that you are in your now. Was I overthinking these philosophical implications?

Comment: You certainly were. The twin paradox provides a good example of the fact that everything happens (that we are aware of) at a common local now. The 'Twin Paradox' provides an example of this. During the turnaround, the travelling twin's plane of simultaneity tilts, so that 'now' for the twin becomes a much later date on distant Earth. But when the traveller returns, the twins still reunite at a common 'now' although they disagree on what year it is.

Comment: @MarcoOcram: In Interstellar, I would say Coop's relationship with his son was dramatically impacted by special relativity. But the amount of astronauts flying near black holes is statistically insignificant to the human population at large.

Comment: @Flater I think you will find that the dominant effect there was time dilation owing to general relativity, not SR. Anyway, my nit-picking is irrelevant- the 'amount' of astronauts flying near black holes is zero.

Comment: What about the contrasting planes of simultaneity does that not mean that there are multiple versions of each observer, like if I am moving away from you my plane of simultaneity cuts your past but from your perspective you're in the future of that event. Isn't there something here we should be worrying about? Like the version of you in my universe is never the same you in your universe. Can we translate between frames to get rid of this problem?

Comment: No, there are not multiple versions of each observer. If you are in a different reference frame to me, you will use different coordinates to specify where I am in spacetime, that's all. I am where I am. It is analogous to using rotated frames of reference to map a country. Two different maps might be oriented at an angle relative to each other, and will therefore use different coordinates to refer to the same places.

Comment: Re. 'multiple versions'. Physicists will generally say absolute simultaneity *would be* unobservable, but by adjusting satellite clocks to match Earth-time [translating between frames] there is a manifold of simultaneity. The friends on these satellites do not become multiple versions. Despite being in different time-flows and ageing at different rates they can all still raise a glass simultaneously at say New Year, GMT. However, synchronising a clock in a gravitational singularity, if it could be attempted, would likely not be possible because the known physics predicts infinite quantities.

Comment: Just want to say thank you so much. You've made me feel a lot better.

Comment: @marcoocram so was my assessment where I said that the notion of you in my reference frame would represent a different version of you than your experience in your reference frame? So if my hypersurface of simultaneity crosscuts your past, it does NOT mean that there's a different version of you in my own reference frame who is having separate experience than the you in your own frame?

Comment: . If you are moving relative to someone else, then yes in theory you will be time dilated in their frame of reference and they will be time dilated in yours.   Could you explain what this could mean. Do you mean that you're slowed down in my frame and I am in yours?

Comment: Loosely, yes. But the true meaning of special relativity is quite subtle, so you need to be careful when drawing conclusions from statements like that.

Comment: Can you promise me as one last question special relativity does not lead to different temporal iterations of each observer in each reference frame. No duplicates or anything. We just apply different coordinates to one another. When we communicate you send signals from your now and I send signals from mine. We each have our own now and that's fine. No copies, nothing like that. Just communication between observers and here on earth that's basically no different to how we thought of it prior to the development of relativity. Thanks so much Marco. This has bothered me.

Comment: Yes, I can categorically promise that all of what you have said in your comment is correct.

Comment: A ship passes Earth, Earthman and pilot see the same image of a western town on Mars with a big town clock reading noon and a sign saying public execute of horse thief at 12:07. due to different measurements of time and distance, they have differing ideas of what time it is on Mars just then. The spaceship might believe it is 12:08 while the Earthman believes it is 12:05. In the Earthman’s reality, the horse thief is still alive. In the space pilot’s reality, the horse thief is already dead. Does this not lead to duplicates or is again related to coordinates

Comment: It is just coordinates. There is one event in which the horse thief is executed. The pilot might give it the coordinate 12:06 while the Earthman might give it the coordinate 12:08. Incidentally, neither can 'see' the event when it happens, as they have to allow for light to come from Mars to meet them...

Comment: If the spaceship happened to be passing Earth at the moment when light from the execution arrived at Earth, then both the pilot and the Earthman would see the execution at the same time.

Comment: I just want to say thanks again, I imagine it can be annoying answering these kind of questions! So, when I am with my girlfriend and think what is she thinking now? Is that a meaningful thing to think? Because obviously our nows may be slightly different.. If you don't have time to answer or find these questions silly please let me know. But the questions themselves are definitely bothering me as I find it all so crazy!

Comment: No problem! If you are stationary relative to you girlfriend, you share a common now. iI you are moving relative to each other, her now will be fractionally out of synch with yours, but the difference will be billions or trillions of times shorter than the response time of your brain, so there is no way you could possibly be aware of any difference.

Comment: So if her now is of sync with me what you mean is that we will apply different coordinates to the events around us due to things like time dilation? Is that what you mean by out of sync now? She is where she is and sends me signals, her perspective exists alongside me but we still have slightly contrasting coordinates for events, an out of sync now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143096/discussion-between-marco-ocram-and-ecologitefacies).

Answer (score 3):

The moment of a conscious thought is a personal now, which you could line up with a time, say 3pm. If your friend is orbiting Earth in a satellite their clock might tick slower, but it can be adjusted to synchronise with your clock.  Using the synchronised time you can raise a glass at the same moment — sharing the 'now' moment.  Nevertheless your friend's time is passing slower than yours; they are aging slower.

In more complex space topologies synchronisation becomes problematic, to the extreme of a gravitational singularity.  If your friend is in a gravitational singularity you will not be able to synchronise clocks.

Answer (score 1):

All of our perceptions (whether you consider special relativity or not) are about the past. There is always some time between an event and our becoming aware of it, and this is mostly dominated by the bio-electrical processes in our sensory nerves and brain, not by relativistic effects, you can safely ignore them in this context.

So in any case there is no true "shared now". The moment you realize something about the world around you is unrelated to the moment someone else realizes the same thing (except of course that these realizations can only happen after the thing happened).

In relationships, what counts is the memory and the awareness of shared experiences, knowledge, and interaction. Since you know that your friends and family members are individuals with a similar brain, you can reasonably assume that they experience similar perceptions as you do. Your familiarity with their way of reasoning (even if it differs from your own) enables you to "simulate" and thereby anticipate their reactions to the events that you both experience, and this is what creates the notion of a shared "now". When you're not currently interacting, the question of whether something happened simultaneously loses much of its relevance, and the shared "now" becomes much more blurred to something like "today" or "this year".

Answer (score -1):

Even in a nonrelativistic sense, temporal asynchrony is observable. Compare the Sentinelese tribe (Andaman Islands, Indian Ocean) who're, for all purposes and intents, in the stone age and New York, USA, perhaps Silicon valley is more apropos, at the leading edge of 21st century technological innovation.

Same goes for certain luminaries e.g. Siddhartha of Buddhism abd especially Mahavira of Jainism developed ethics only practicable in the distant future when the technology necessary becomes available.

Time is not exactly moving at the same rate for everybody.