# The significance of the NOW

Tags: time

This is a final summary of my concerns. I've asked similar questions but this is a summary. I hope you clever people can alleviate my confusion and nervousness.

Special Relativity says there is no meaningful notion of now. Now doesn't exist, it's not invariant but entirely observer dependent.

Conscious experience, if assumed materialistic is a product of physical processes which happen over time. If there is no now is there any meaning to the question 'what are you thinking now?'.

I gather hear on Earth there is very little difference between different observers. So we can pretty reasonably say what's happening now for you.

Is it time we detached ourselves entirely from the importance of a now moment? Conscious experience like our own takes place over time. All obsevers have their own now delineated by the light cone structure. All observers nows are valid, so do we communicate through our own nows, sure physical processes happen in the universe but attributing a physically significant notion of now is not important.

Does Special Relativity change how i should think of you and your identity, are you conscious irrespective of my reference frame. Should someone rationally worry about the implications of such a lack of a global now.

Are my concerns unfounded. Are others conscious with me.

Thank you

Comment: "Special Relativity says there is no meaningful notion of now." Or doesn't say that. It says that people will observe time pass differently, but they can still have synchronicity. If You leave your twin to go in a super fast rocket and your twin has the necessary data (your acceleration, etc) he can use the equations of special relativity to know what time it is in your clock at any moment. This is how GPS works.

Comment: You've asked essentially the same question before and accepted a highly-upvoted answer to it. Why is it necessary to repeat this? Just read that answer! https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/96564/how-meaningful-is-the-notion-of-now-here-on-earth

Comment: It is peculiar that people get worked up over now, but not over the brain not being a mathematical point. Electric impulses need to travel back and forth between neurons for thinking to take place even under classical physics, so "now" in "what are you thinking now" is only [*specious* present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specious_present). Special relativity simply merges separate temporal and spatial localizations into a single spacetime localization of *events*, but it does not add anything relevantly new concerning mind functioning.

Comment: Also "what are you thinking now?" has never been an unambiguous question from the starter. What do you mean "now"? The moment the questioner thinks about asking? The moment they utter the question? The moment the listener ears it? The moment their brain starts processing it or the momeNtbthey are ready to answer? What If the question was typed and sent via chat with a lag of a few seconds, or sent by paper mail? Are such "moments" even possible to define unambiguously?

Comment: *Now doesn't exist, it's not invariant but entirely observer dependent.* If now doesn't exist, then how is it observer dependent?

Comment: Look in to Nonduality.

Comment: You are talking about Eternlism, a view which Einstein certainly had. But there is also Presentism, the idea there is only now, & how the past & future are recorded or implied within it. GR looks like the former, the Wheeler-DeWitt equation looks like the latter.

Comment: Interesting query. To my reckoning, the NOW is as tangibly real as a cat is.

Comment: "Special Relativity says there is no meaningful notion of now."  No, that is wrong. Relativity shows that there is no definition of simultaneity over different points of space. That is different from denying the existence of a "now". And the mere fact that relativity views all of spacetime as a whole does not deny the existence of now, either.

Comment: What about here on Earth, like if walk towards you and away my hypersurface of simultaneity tilts into future / past respectively. Does this really not mean anything important?, does anything change for how we think of one another

Answer (score 2):

You are quite wrong in saying that there is no meaningful notion of 'now' in SR.

In SR all particles are travelling along timelines through a 4d spacetime. Each particle exists at a 4d point, which is the 'here' and 'now' for that particle.

What SR does undermine is the idea that you can extrapolate 'now' from one point of space to all others simply by projecting out normal to your own time axis.

Your concerns are entirely unfounded. Consider the concept of level. In London, level means a plane tangential to the surface of the Earth at London. In New York, level means a plane tangential to the surface of the Earth at New York. The two definitions disagree. Were you to extrapolate sea level in London to New York it would appear in New York to be a sloping plane thousands of metres above the city, and New York would be below London sea level. Does that have an effect on the consciousness of people in New York? Of course not. It is just a coordinate convention. Ten different people walking in ten different directions on Andromeda would label 'now' on Earth with ten different time stamps, but that again is just a labelling convention- it does not make any difference to our consciousness on Earth.

Comment: Is this the case even if the Block universe is true? Am I really being silly here?

Comment: I gather this could only possibly be the case if one believed in your version of block time, where the whole block does not exist. This is not the standard view of time. My question regards anxieties regarding this standard view

Comment: What I have explained to you is the significance of 'now' according to Special Relativity, which is the current mainstream physical theory about flat spacetime. The 'block universe' view is not a 'standard' view of time, and even if it were, I suspect you are misinterpreting it, just as you have misinterpreted SR. What you are thinking now is what you are thinking now. It is quite different to what you were thinking last week or what you might be thinking next week. Your are conscious in the present.

Comment: So can you guarantee me, that even if block time is true in its most 4d extent nothing here changed how we should think of each other. I am still mistaken and wrong to be anxious

Comment: I categorically guarantee it.

Comment: @MarcoOcram your second paragraph here is somewhat incorrect. If you're working in 4-space, *Events* are at points in 4-space. Processes (including particles) are static 4-dimensional objects. If you imagine a height-vs-time plot of a ball tossed straight up, in 3-space plus time, the ball is a sphere and the plot shows its trajectory; in 4-space the ball is a hypertube whose cross-section is a sphere, and the plot is a picture of the center of the ball. There's no extra hyperclock tracking the cross-section's procession along the time axis with respect to hypertime.

Comment: @gs many thanks, but that  is beside my point. Let's suppose we take the worldline of an atomic clock. All along the word line are the events of the individual transitions of Caesium. My point is that if you take the event corresponding to one particular transition, that event is in a region of spacetime where the clock was located when the event happened.

Comment: Again, does this have no impact on obsverers if block time is true. Similarly, if I approach you and my worldline tilts there isn't another version of you. Also you don't fly back and forth through time as I move